# Upper bound about Gaussian tail bound

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities

From the definition of sub-Gaussian distribution $X$ w.r.t. $\sigma$ i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\geq t) \leq 2 \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}).$$

It's natural that when $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$,
$$\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t) \leq \exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}).$$

But this bound is too loose since when $t=0$, $\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t) = \frac{1}{2} << 1$.

Thus I guessed somehow

$$\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t) \leq \frac{1}{2}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}) \tag{1}$$

when $t\geq0$.

It can be verfied using the computer that $(1)$ is true. But how to prove it?

---

Mill's inequality $$\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t) \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\frac{t}{\sigma}}$$ helps solve my guess when $t$ is big. But when $t$ is near zero, how to solve it?

---

I have previously mistyped $\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t)$ by $\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\leq t)$. Great thanks to [Brendan McKay](https://mathoverflow.net/users/9025/brendan-mckay) to point this out!

Comment: You have some inequalities backwards.  $P(X-\mu\le t)$ increases with $t$.  Perhaps you mean  $P(X-\mu\ge t)$.

Comment: Your problem reduces clearly to finding an exponential bound on the error function. You might find some solutions there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting
$Z:=\frac{X-\mu}\sigma$ and $z:=\frac t\sigma$, rewrite the inequality in question as
$$d(z):=P(Z\ge z)-e^{-z^2/2}/2\le0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for real $z\ge0$.

Note that
$$d'(z)=(z-\sqrt{2/\pi})e^{-z^2/2}/2.$$
So, $d$ is decreasing on the interval $[0,\sqrt{2/\pi}]$ and increasing on the interval $[\sqrt{2/\pi},\infty)$. Also,$d(0)=0$ and $d(z)\to0$ as $z\to\infty$. So, inequality \eqref{1} follows. $\quad\Box$

Comment: The key is to take derivative and the derivative of CDF is exactly PDF. Nice proof!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, in the [wiki article for error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#cite_note-13) $\Phi(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$, they go over many formulas. One nice one is the exact Craig's formula (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150504/how-demonstrate-the-craig-representation-for-the-gaussian-probability-function))

$$\Phi(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-x^{2}/(sin\theta)^{2}}d\theta,x\geq 0$$

from which "New Exponential Bounds and Approximations for the Computation of Error Probability in Fading" derives a similar bound to yours with $1/2$

$$\Phi(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-2x^{2}}+e^{-x^{2}}).$$

For small x this behaves like $e^{-x^2}$. So if our density is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$ then we have

$$P[N(0,1)>x]=\int_{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(x/\sqrt{2})\leq \frac{1}{4}(e^{-x^{2}}+e^{-x^{2}/2}),$$

and so indeed for small $x$ we get $1/2$ and we also get the inequality $\frac{1}{4}(e^{-x^{2}}+e^{-x^{2}/2})<\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^{2}/2}.$

As mentioned there, one can get increasingly better approximations on the constants: by $\sin$ monotonicity we have for $0=\theta_0\leq \theta_{1}\leq ...\leq \theta_{N}=\pi/2$

$\begin{align}\Phi(x)\leq& \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\theta_{i-1}}^{\theta_{i}}e^{-x^{2}/(sin\theta_{i})^{2}}d\theta\\
=&\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{i}e^{-x^{2}/(b_{i})^{2}}
\end{align}$

for $a_i=\frac{2(\theta_{i}-(\theta_{i-1})}{\pi}$ and $b_i=\frac{1}{(sin\theta_{i})^{2}}.$ The above was for $N=2$ and $\theta_1=\pi/4$ and so one can get better constants as N grows.